# How to use DRY methods with OS commands with Python and classes

Tags: object-oriented, python-3.x, dry

My goal is  to learn more about OOP patterns and use DRY principles. I am trying this for wrapping an os command that interacts with a database using classes:

This works fine:

```
import subprocess

class Blah:
    
    command = '/usr/bin/database_exec '
    
    def execute(self, action, user):
        self.action = action
        self.user   = user
        self.command = f"{Blah.command} {self.action} {self.user}"
        self.sp = subprocess.Popen(
                                    self.command,shell=True,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        return self.sp.communicate()

try:
    cmd = Blah()
    output, err = cmd.execute('delete', 'user1')
    output, err = cmd.execute('modify', 'user1')
    output, err = cmd.execute('add', 'user1') 
    # ...etc...  
    print(f"O: {output} E: {err}")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Is it pythonic to pass 'verbs' / parts of the command like like that?

This seems to present an easier to use interface with explicit 'verbs':

```
class Blah:
    
    command = '/usr/local/blah'
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.sp = subprocess.Popen(self.command,
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        
    def remove(self):
        self.action = 'remove'
        self.sp.communicate()

    def add(self):
        self.action = 'add'
        self.sp.communicate()
```

But seems to get repetitive and difficult to modify command once the instance of sp is created.  I could instantiate the sub process each time but that's also repetitive?

What sort of patterns or ways of thinking would better than this for reusable , modular code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use OOP for this. Use a procedural function.